# How to prevent Amazon S3 object expiration from deleting the directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We want to delete temp files from the S3 bucket from one of the folder on daily basis. I have tried with s3 lifecycle policy. For example my folder name is Test, I have set prefix for expiration is Test/ . But the issue here is along with all the files, Test folder is also getting deleted. I want to keep the folder as is and only delete the files in that . Is there any way i can do this?

Comment: I am not too sure about this but have you tried using `Test/*` instead ?

Comment: Site-note: Folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3. The Key (filename) of objects contains the full path. So, you can create files in a 'Test' folder simply by creating a file in that folder, even if it doesn't exist. To force a folder to 'appear', the S3 console creates a zero-length object with the name of the folder. It is possible that this file is being deleted by the lifecycle policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about the folder.

As soon as you have at least one file "in" the folder (object key beginning with `Test/`) it will appear again and when there are no objects beginning with that key prefix it will disappear -- all of this is normal/expected behavior because folders in S3 are not containers like they are on a filesystem and they do not actually need to exist before putting files "in" them.

Comment: In 2022, S3 does have ["folder" objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-folders.html). They are just empty files, but their existence can be significant. Not sure when that was introduced, but [maybe in 2021](https://web.archive.org/web/20210401000000*/https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-folders.html). Anyway, example of significance: if you try to set up a remote backup from a Plesk server to an S3 bucket subfolder, you will get a _target not found_ error unless the "folder" already exists.